# Building go tests from multiple packages into single file

Tags: go, go-testing, go-build

Is there any way to build all the test files in a project located inside multiple packages into a single binary file?
To build binary inside a single package, I could use
`go test -c`.

I need something like `go test ./... -c`,but this returns "cannot use -c flag with multiple packages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to build all the test files in a project located inside multiple packages into a single binary file?

No.